# How to quantize specific layers on OpenVINO Workbench?

Tags: intel, workbench, openvino

I have a trained onnx model that needs to be quantized to INT8. But I want my last fully connected layers are still in FP32 or FP16. So how can I choose specific layers to quantize (or not to quantize)?

PS when I was working with NNCF, I just use parametr ignored_scopes. Maybe is there something similar here at Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

Use "ignored" parameter in configuration file to exclude nodes or operation types from optimization.

```
        "algorithms": [
        {
            "name": "DefaultQuantization", // Optimization algorithm name
            "params": {
                "ignored": {
                    // List of nodes that are excluded from optimization
                    "scope": [
                        "<NODE_NAME>"
                    ],
                    // List of types that are excluded from optimization
                    "operations": [
                        {
                            "type": "<NODE_TYPE>",
                            // Includes excluding by attributes
                            "attributes": {
                                "<NAME>": "<VALUE>" // Lists of values is not included
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "<NODE_TYPE>" // Excluding only by type
                        }
                    ]
                }
```